# deserialization: "Type Is not supported for deserialization of an Array"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, vb.net, deserialization

This code is giving me an error message when I click on a button that removes a layer:

```
$scope.removeLayer = function () {
    var data = {'layerArr': convertedLayerArray,}}
```

I am getting an error message:

"Type 'WebCE.LayerArrVb' is not supported for deserialization of an array."

Here is the relevant class, web method and ajax call:

```
Public Class LayerArrVb
Public Property absoluteEndM As Integer
Public Property absoluteStartM As Integer
Public Property endDate As String
Public Property endMetres As Integer
Public Property layerDate As String
Public Property name As String
Public Property startMetres As Integer
Public Property thickness As Integer
End Class


<WebMethod>
Public Function ChartInfo(layerArr As List(Of LayerArrVb)) As List(Of 
LayerArrVb)
    Return layerArr
End Function
```

I had to create ConvertedLayerArray due there being a JSON incompatible date format:

```
convertedLayerArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < layerArr2.length; ++i) {
            var convertedEndDate = new 
            Date(parseInt(layerArr2[i].endDate.substr(6)));
            var convertedEndDate2 = convertedEndDate.getFullYear() + ' ' + 
             (convertedEndDate.getMonth() + 1) + ' ' + 
             convertedEndDate.getDate();

            var convertedLayerDate = new 
             Date(parseInt(layerArr2[i].layerDate.substr(6)));
            var convertedLayerDate2 = convertedLayerDate.getFullYear() + ' 
            ' + (convertedLayerDate.getMonth() + 1) + ' ' + 
             convertedLayerDate.getDate();

            convertedLayerArray.push({
                "absoluteEndM": layerArr2[i].absoluteEndM,
                "absoluteStartM": layerArr2[i].absoluteStartM,
                "endDate": convertedEndDate2,
                "endMetres": layerArr2[i].endMetres,
                "layerDate": convertedLayerDate2,
                "name": layerArr2[i].name,
                "startMetres": layerArr2[i].startMetres,
                "thickness": layerArr2[i].thickness
            });
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/ChartInfo",
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "layerArr": convertedLayerArray}),
            success: function (data) {
                result = data;
            },
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                alert("Ajax call to ChartInfo failed");
            }
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shoud add `<Serializable()>` attribute to your class as following

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class LayerArrVb
Public Property absoluteEndM As Integer
Public Property absoluteStartM As Integer
Public Property endDate As String
Public Property endMetres As Integer
Public Property layerDate As String
Public Property name As String
Public Property startMetres As Integer
Public Property thickness As Integer
End Class
```

Apply the `SerializableAttribute` attribute to a type to indicate that instances of this type can be serialized.
you can read it documentation from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netframework-4.8)